# Difference between leaflet Marker and mapbox featureLayer

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I understood that I can use the general Leaflet `layer`, and the more advanced map-box `featureLayer`, that provides useful functions as the filter.
However, I don't understand the difference between

```
marker = L.Marker (new L.LatLng(lat, lng), 
        {
            icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon(
                                {'marker-color': 'fc4353'
                                 'marker-size': 'large'
                                }),
            title: name,
        });
map.addLayer(marker);
```

and

```
     var poijson =  {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [lng, lat]
            },
            "properties": {
              "title": poi.name,
              "marker-color": "#fc4353",
              "marker-size": "large"
            }
          }; 
     map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
```

Is it just the same?

**[UPDATE]**

Moreover, if I had many markers, should I add a new layer for each marker? It seems not a good thing for performance..
For instance, If I do:

```
 var pois; //loaded with pois info
 var geojson=[]; //will contain geojson data
 for (p=0; p< pois.length; p++)
        {
         var poi = pois[p];
         var poijson =  
           {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": 
             {
              "type": "Point",
              "coordinates": [poi.lng, poi.lat]
             }
           }; 
         geojson.push(poijson); 
        }
 map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);
```

Does it will create many layers for each `poi`, or just one layer with all the markers?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

When you add a marker to a Leaflet map via `map.addLayer(marker);`, the marker is added to the 'leaflet-maker-pane'. The markers are plain images/icons.

You can use a geoJSON layer to draw GIS features: points, lines, polygons, etc.
See here: http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Mapbox's [featureLayers](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.8/l-mapbox-featurelayer/) is just an extension to Leaflet's [geoJSONLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson)

To add multiple markers, call `addMarker` multiple times. Leaflet will create a new layer for each of the markers. Each marker will be added as an image element to the `leaflet-marker-pane` div:
http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9150014

**Updated response:**

If you add a GeoJSON layer with multiple features, Leaflet will create separate layer for each of the features. You can inspect the layers of the map by calling `map._layers` after adding the GeoJSON Layer.

`marker.addTo(map)` and `map.addLayer(marker)` are doing the same thing. 
Here's the `addTo` function taken from [the source](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Layer.js)

```
addTo: function (map) {
    map.addLayer(this);
    return this;
},
```

Comment: in the example you linked, it does   `marker = new L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map)`. As I know, `marker.addTo(map)` is the same as `map.addLayer(marker)`  so I am adding new layers as well. Am i wrong? I want to have just one layer for each marker category, not one layer each marker.

Comment: even better (and easy), let's say just one layer for all the markers. If I use `map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson)` and `geojson` is an array of markers encoded as Features, will it create just one layer or multiple layers? I add this to the main question

Comment: Leaflet will create layer for each of the features. You can inspect the layers of the map by calling `map._layers` after adding the GeoJSON Layer.